# How to wrap an element around an iframe or embed in content automatically?

Tags: filters, the-content

Id like to have wordpress automatically wrap a div around any `iframe` or `embed` when they are used in `the_content`...how might this be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try jQuery

```
$('iframe').wrap('<div class="wrapper" />');
```

Comment: This actually ended up being a simpler and more useful solution later after realizing that the php function was targeting too broad of a spectrum of iframes thoughout the site.

Comment: Of course this won't work if the browser has JavaScript disabled.

Answer (score 21):

Here's the solution I used:

```
function wrap_embed_with_div($html, $url, $attr) {

     return '<div class="video-container">' . $html . '</div>';

}

 add_filter('embed_oembed_html', 'wrap_embed_with_div', 10, 3);
```

Comment: If I am not wrong, for the filter to work, the last line should be: `add_filter( 'embed_oembed_html', 'wrap_embed_with_div', 10, 4 );`

Comment: The last parameter in [add_filter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter) is accepted_args, which is an integer indicating the number of arguments accepted by the function, which in this case is 3.

Comment: that is correct @user23385, the 4th argument would be `$post_id`. whilst in your answer you only make use of argument 1. so it would be save to skip the `10` (default) and the `3` since you only need `1` and that would also be default.. (but than you would also need to delete `$url` & `$attr` in your function) thanks for the answer, though, exactly what i needed :)

Answer (score 9):

With Wordpress filters. Add this to your functions.php:

```
function div_wrapper($content) {
    // match any iframes
    $pattern = '~<iframe.*</iframe>|<embed.*</embed>~';
    preg_match_all($pattern, $content, $matches);

    foreach ($matches[0] as $match) {
        // wrap matched iframe with div
        $wrappedframe = '<div>' . $match . '</div>';

        //replace original iframe with new in content
        $content = str_replace($match, $wrappedframe, $content);
    }

    return $content;    
}
add_filter('the_content', 'div_wrapper');
```

Comment: Apologies for the late response, Ive away for work...this looks very promising, Ill give it a go and report back.

Comment: This works great, but is there any way to limit the wrapper to only output once after detecting the first iframe or embedded object?...

Comment: You could use [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) instead of preg_match_all to only get one result. Or rewrite the foreach to break after the first iteration. Or not use a foreach and just get the first match ($match = $matches[0]). Just make sure you check if you've gotten any matches first.

Comment: This is f-ing awesome! I used this to ensure videos are responsive with bootstrap helper class: `$wrappedframe = '<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">' . $match . '</div>';`

Comment: I have hundreds of iframes on my site and I added this chunk of code to my functions.php file and nothing happened.  I have tried using jQuery and several other methods and no matter what I do I cant wrap a div around my iframes.